# How do I get the unique id of ember object when object is initialized?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have instantiated the model using createRecord. Now how do I get the id of that record before it is saved ?

Comment: Sounds like you're using ember-data. If so, add the tag to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the `generateIdForRecord`

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_generateIdForRecord

> If the globally unique IDs for your records should be generated on the
>   client, implement the generateIdForRecord() method. This method will
>   be invoked each time you create a new record, and the value returned
>   from it will be assigned to the record's primaryKey.
>
> Most traditional REST-like HTTP APIs will not use this method.
>   Instead, the ID of the record will be set by the server, and your
>   adapter will update the store with the new ID when it calls
>   didCreateRecord(). Only implement this method if you intend to
>   generate record IDs on the client-side.

You can even create model specific adapter say `post` model, you can create `post` adapter and override `generateIdForRecord` method.

**adapters/post.js**

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  generateIdForRecord: function(store, inputProperties) {
    return v4();
  }
});
```

Comment: Yea, this is likely the solution. It's important to note that the default behavior of ember-data is NOT to generate ids. If you want client side id generation you must implement it as described by @kumkanillam here

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)