# Ember Data 2.10.0 How to generate Id's Client Side

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to create Ids for newly created ember data records on the client side.

What is the recommended way to to this?

Comment: Could you use `Ember.guidFor()` method? API link [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_guidFor).

Comment: Sorry about the "is right" issue. No this Method is not right. I need a solution for an createRecord with store.createRecord. I think i going to greate a service, which holds the current stage of the Ids to auto_ingrement

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628814/how-do-i-get-the-unique-id-of-ember-object-when-object-is-initialized/40629256#40629256)

Answer (score 1):

Update of the link to `Ember.guid()` in comment above. [Ember v3.4 API](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.4/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Finternals/guidFor)

Import it from Ember's internals as follows:

```
import { guidFor } from '@ember/object/internals';
```